# Prove it exists integers so to write character as linear combination.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G$ be a group and suppose that $\chi$ is a character on $G$. Furthermore, suppose that $\chi(g)$ is constant for all $g \not=1$, prove it exists integers $a,b$ such that $$\chi=a1_G + b\chi_0$$ where $1_G$ is the principal character and $\chi_0$ is the regular character.

The hint was to prove first that it exists $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the equality holds and the proceed from there. I managed to do that, if $\chi(g)=a_1$ for $g \not=1$, we have $$\chi=a_1 1_G + \frac{1-a_1}{\mid G \mid} \chi_0$$ but I don't know how to proceed from here, since the chosen $a,b$ at the moment aren't necessarily integers. Any help?

Comment: To clarify, $\chi$ is the character of some finite dimensional representation of $G$ over $\mathbb{C}$?  And $\chi_0$ is the character of the regular representation?

Comment: @D_S Yes, thanks for the clarification.